# Como acessar de outro computador a aplicação rodando em localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma aplicação web feita em ASP.NET MVC 5, e dei um *start* nela pelo Visual Studio 2013, o endereço da Index page ficou assim na máquina onde está rodando: `http://localhost:51144/`.

Como faço para outro computador da rede acessar minha aplicação?

Comment: Olá, dá uma olhada nesse link aqui tem várias pessoas discutindo sobre o assunto: [Development Server LocalHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730280/accessing-asp-net-development-server-from-another-pc-on-the-network) Dizem que não é uma boa prática, mas é possível se voce liberar algumas portas.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [IIS montar server em PC em casa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167437/iis-montar-server-em-pc-em-casa)

Answer (score 4):

Se você tiver o IIS (*Internet Information Servces*) instalado em sua máquina, você pode hospedar sua aplicação como um site lá. Outros computadores da rede podem acessá-lo usando http://`<nome do seu computador>`/NomeDoSite.

Para testar se o IIS está instalado abra o browser e acesse `http://localhost`.
[image: Testando se o IIS está instalado]

Caso não tenha o IIS instalado, veja como habilitá-lo nesse link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181052(v=vs.80).aspx

Para saber como criar um site no IIS dê uma olhada nesse link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/tcywfea7(v=vs.80).aspx

Outra opção é você **publicar sua aplicação diretamente pelo Visual Studio**, veja esse artigo com um passo a passo: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2596/learn-iis-host-and-publish-in-mvc5-using-visual-studio-2013-rc