# IIS montar server em PC em casa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, iis, servidor-de-aplicação

Olá, preciso saber se tem como eu configurar, etc, o IIS em um notebook, para que quando este notebook estiver ligado na empresa, ele funcione como o meu servidor, de forma que eu possa acessar minha aplicação ASP.NET MVC através de outros dispositivos...

Eu quero acessar o site como se ele estivesse numa hospedagem contratada, porém nesse caso ele estaria rodadando em um notebook na minha sala...

Tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sim. Tem como. Eu não sei até que ponto essa pergunta é pertinente pro nosso site, mas vou te explicar mesmo assim, sucintamente, em poucos passos.

#### Instalar o IIS

- Entrar em **programas e recursos**
- Adicionar recursos ao Windows
- Marcar a checkbox **gerenciador de serviços da internet** e as opções "internas" que desejar

#### Permitir acesso externo

Tendo o IIS instalado, é necessário que seu computador possa ser acessado externamente. Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre isso, mas será necessário criar regras de redirecionamento no modem/roteador. Basicamente você precisa encaminhar as requisições que chegarem em determinada porta (geralmente se usa a porta 80) para o IP interno da máquina que vai ter a aplicação.

[Nessa resposta tem algumas dicas que podem ajudar.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50934/3635)

#### Permitir o acesso no firewall

Outra coisa necessária é permitir que seu computador seja acessado por outras máquinas, liberando nos firewalls, antivírus e afins. Também não vou entrar em detalhes, até porque cada aplicação tem uma forma diferente de tratar isso.

#### Ter um IP fixo

Também será necessário ter um IP externo fixo apontando pra sua rede. Esse serviço pode ser contratado com a sua provedora de banda larga, não faço ideia de como estão os preços. Também tem a possibilidade de deixar um serviço como no No-IP rodando na máquina. Com um serviço desses, é possível "mapear" um endereço para o sua rede, mesmo sem IP fixo. O que este serviço faz é apontar este endereço para seu IP externo, é necessário que ele sempre fique rodando, pois quando o IP externo mudar, o serviço precisa atualizar isso.

---

Depois de fazer estas configurações é só publicar a aplicação normalmente no IIS e acessar pelo browser usando o IP fixo ou o endereço fornecido pelos serviços de DNS.

Comment: Também é possível hospedar a aplicacao em vários servidores públicos gratuitos. Por exemplo [no appharbor](https://appharbor.com/). [pergunta relevante no SOEN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008718/is-there-an-equivalent-to-heroku-for-the-asp-net-platform). Se o intuito for usar apenas o servidor dentro de casa. O acesso através do nome do computador pode ser mais indicado. Isto implicaria que os computadores estariam na mesma rede.

Comment: Acho pouco provável que o intuito seja usar dentro de casa porque ele mencionou que acessaria da empresa. De qualquer forma, vale o aviso pro AP. E também, as dicas de hospedagens.