# Acessar aplicação JSP pela web

Tags: aplicação-web, servidor, servidor-de-aplicação

Faço algumas aplicações pequenas com Javascript, HTML que consigo deixar em um computador rodando na empresa em que trabalho, e todos da rede interna conseguem acessa-las pelo endereço http://servidor:8080/GO/aplicacao.jsp.

Minha dúvida é como eu faria para uma aplicação poder ser acessada de qualquer computador? **Não só na rede interna**.

Comment: Vinculada: [IIS montar server em PC em casa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167437/18246)

Comment: Só pra deixar claro: mesmo que as duas perguntas linkadas respondam sua pergunta, não exclua a sua. Duplicatas são importantes para o site =D