# Como publicar site feito no Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Criei um site em MVC no Visual Studio 2017.

Quero saber como gerar os arquivos necessários pro site funcionar e em que pasta eu devo incluí-los.

Comment: Italo, você precisa saber como hospeda desde o zero, ou como gera os arquivos para serem publicados? Não consegui entender direito. Posso ajudar você na questão da compilação do projeto, se for desde o zero posso estar estudando e te auxiliando.

Comment: pode ser desde o zero. a diferença é que não irei contratar um plano de hospedagem, irei usar em minha rede local pelo meu IP

Comment: Possível duplicata de [IIS montar server em PC em casa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167437/iis-montar-server-em-pc-em-casa)

Comment: Vi o conteúdo da outra pergunta e irá me ajudar bastante, alterei a pergunta para as dúvidas que tenho e que não constam lá.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Para publicar um site no Visual studio 2017

Clique com o botão direito em cima do seu projeto e depois clique em publish
[image: publicando site no visual studio]

Depois escolha uma a **Folder** e dê um caminho para a pasta ou deixe o padrão e depois clique em publish

[image: Opções de deploy]

Para publicar no iis vai em `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` crie uma pasta  e copie o todo o conteúdo da pasta publishOutput para esta pasta

Criar site no IIS

[image: Adicionando um novo site no iis]

Configure o nome do site, o caminho da pasta que você criou em wwwroot e a porta se for necessário alterar( lembre-se que pode ser necessário abrir no firewall) e depois clique em ok

[image: Configurando iis]

Comment: como eu escolho a porta que quero usar?

Comment: como acesso o iis (essa última imagem que voce postou)?

Comment: fiz tudo como está nos dois posts (nesse e no que me foi indicado). O site está no ar, mas ao invés de mostrar a página, mostra uma lista dos arquivos dentro da pasta

Comment: Então tem coisa errada com o seu site,  por padrão o iis não permite listar o diretório, apenas se você alterar esta configuração, Agora se você copiou todo o conteúdo da pasta de deploy para dentro da pasta do iis, era pra mostrar o site ou qualquer outro erro menos listar o diretório. Dá uma olhada na pasta vê se está tudo certo,Web.config, se for MVC olha se tem o arquivo Global.asax

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, você resolveu minha dúvida quanto às configurações. irei fazer mais uns testes amanhã e qualquer coisa eu crio outra pergunta sobre o iis estar listando os arquivos. abraço