# Como um site é publicado e hospedado na internet?

Tags: php, mysql, hospedagem

A minha duvida é como um site feito com PHP e MySQL é publicado na internet? E como se hospeda nele num servidor online?

Comment: Você não tem as configurações da conexão do mysql nos seus arquivos php? localhost etc... Basta mudar para o servidor de hospedagem, você não tem os arquivos organizados nas suas pastas do localhost? Basta colocados na pasta do servidor de hospedagem...

Comment: Entendo, e um site como um portal de noticias, como ele é atualizado em cada noticia no servidor de hospedagem? Seria outra pergunta isso?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167437/18246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um servidor Web é a grosso modo uma máquina com um sistema operacional, um software de servidor web(no caso do php o Apache ou outro), um software de servidor de banco de dados e um software de aplicação, o site, com seu front-end(html,js) e back-end(php).

Um ip fixo é atribuído a essa máquina, um servidor de DNS fica responsável por traduzir o domínio(www.exemplo.com.br) para o ip correspondente (`33.155.109.105`).

A partir do momento que o ip é atribuído ao servidor que por sua vez tem uma porta configurada para ficar `full time` aguardando requisições, o site está no ar sendo acessado pelo `ip` (`http://33.155.109.105`) ou pelo domínio configurado (`http://www.exemplo.com`).

Quando uma requisição é realizada ex: `http://www.exemplo.com/uma_página.php`,
o servidor vai procurar em sua pasta raiz o arquivo `uma_página.php`, que por sua vez exibirá o resultado de seu processamento como resposta para a requisição.

Sua pergunta é ampla, então não é de costume haver respostas genéricas como essa, que tem como principal objetivo incentivá-lo a pesquisar as minúcias de como isso funciona aqui no site, existem respostas muito boas.